# Trying a scripted google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am a bit new to spreadsheet scripting and I have a project that I am trying to accomplish.

**Overview:**

I am making spreadsheet that records reading progress. 
The first column (A) is the date.
Second Column (B) is the required time to be spent reading.
Third column (C) is the amount on minutes spent reading.
Fourth column (D)is the bonus minutes which are described below.
Fifth column (E) is the result of (Effort+Bonus-Requirement)

If you spend over 30 minutes (let's say 30+x minutes) , the extra is used to add 1 minute for the next x days. So if you spent 37 minutes reading the next 7 days you will get a bonus of 1 minute so you need to spend 29 minutes instead of the usual 30 for the next 7 days.

However the bonus can accumulate and stack. if you spend 37 minutes on the first day, the next day you are required to do 29 minutes but if instead you did a total of 35 minutes then the next 5 days (after the 2nd day) will get another 1 bonus minute so the 3rd day would have a total of 2 minutes bonus. So the bigger picture in this example will be that the 2nd day gets +1, 3rd to 7th will get 2 minutes and the 8th day will get 1 min (from the first day not the 2nd).

**Other criteria to address:**

The maximum bonus to calculate is uncapped, so if the user was required to spend 30 minutes reading and they spent 150 minutes the bonus of 120 minutes would be added as 1 minute each day for the next 120 days.

The bonus is stackable with no limit, if the total exceeds the required daily limits it would be treated normally, you can reach and exceed the required 30 minutes through bonus alone and it would be treated normally. If you have a stacked bonus of 35 minutes at one day it would be treated as "goal achieved + 5 minutes bonus" even before such day arrives. yet there is nothing to prevent over achieving on that day to increase the bonus.

**My effort**

I have done some scripting using google sheets javascript but the issue is that I had to create a function that I need to use in every cell since from what I've understood scripts can not use setValue() on cells other than the ones its called in.

Also the way functions work is that they are only called at the moment you set the cell to "=myFunction()" and do not change once set even if you change the cells used as inputs.

**Some Code**

This is the function that I created, it works fine however I need it to be persistent and do the calculation in real time.

```
function c() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var thisCell = activeSheet.getCurrentCell();
  var thisColumn = thisCell.getColumn();
  var thisRow = thisCell.getRow();
  var finalValue = 0;

  for (var i = 2; i< thisRow; i++) {
    //if the value in cell Ei is greater than the difference between (thisRow-i) then increment cell
    if (activeSheet.getRange("E"+i).getValue() >= (thisRow-i)){
    Logger.log(activeSheet.getRange("E"+i).getValue());  
    finalValue++;
    }
  }

  return (finalValue);
  Logger.log("final "+finalValue);
}
```

I hope my problem is clear enough for you.

Comment: Welcome. Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1elPrMRH2h5W3Z5b_oUpnUxrZoaY3MzqMlI-WKSLf-Dg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The requirements for your scenario are somewhat ambiguous; you didn't say whether there is a cap to the cumulative time bonus; you assume a script-based answer but you didn't include a manually-calculated example of a successful outcome in your spreadsheet. In order to understand the scenario, I have constructed a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-YN9mdj3WoZMku9BHPZvQle7iUAOe5qzgLEdZcoyrIU/edit?usp=sharing) that I think addresses your problem. It is view only, so you will need to make a copy see the formula. FWIW, I've assumed that there is a cap on bonus time of 10 days.

Comment: On a tangent, we each experience a given social environment with students of differing needs and attitudes. That said, your reward system is intriguing; it can reduce daily reading time-a thing important in reading development. FWIW, my spouse is an experienced teacher of literacy in grades K to 6 in Sydney. Students are encouraged to read as much as they can-the more the better; improvement in reading ability/comprehension is the goal. Reward systems are important but focus on non-reading rewards such as peer recognition, certificates and stickers, advancement in reading groups and so on.

Comment: thank you for the effort, However I was aiming for an uncapped bonus, such that theoretically if you push yourself you can reach a day that there is 0 reading requirements.
My main problem was doing it with an uncapped check, such that if you get a bonus of 17 minutes or more it would carry on.
There was an extra idea for later to first use the bonus minutes to compensate for the past days before adding them to the upcoming days but that is for a later stage.

Comment: The solution provided by @Tedinoz makes sense to me. Formulas are more appropriate than Apps Script in this case. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I think formulas are not sufficient for the scale I want, for example some days I can get more than 100 minutes bonus which I should distribute over the next 100 days. I can clearly see that it works well on a smaller scale though.

Comment: @Lechiro May I respectfully suggest that you edit your question to indicate the period over which reading is tracked, the uncapped nature of the bonus and any other factors that are relevant to a user who wishes to read and investigate this problem.

Comment: @Tedinoz done, thanks for the guidelines and I apologize if the idea wasnt clear before as this is my first time posting here.

Comment: @Lechiro As a matter of interest, is this a programming assignment, or a genuine reading-tracking project?

Comment: @Tedinoz Actually it is a reading-tracking project that my brother needed. he is doing PhD and has a lot of reading material to finish and he thought of this idea which I liked.